# One liner conditional, multiple variables and check that all of them are not false?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

How I can make a conditional in python that checks for this three keywords defined in the dictionary and that they are not `False` ?

```
settings = {
    'proxy_host': '127.0.0.1',
    'proxy_port': 8080,
    'proxy_protocol': 'socks',
}
```

I have tried with the sentence you can see below. But this is only checking that these keywords exists in the dictionary `settings` without bothering about what type of value has.

```
if 'proxy_host' and 'proxy_port' and 'proxy_protocol' in settings:
```

I only want my IF to True If none of the keywords are falsely and they all exist as keys.

Comment: Which version of Python you are using?

Comment: Your `if` statement is **not** checking that those keywords are keys of the dictionary `settings`.  Try this: `print('a' and 'b' and 'proxy_host' in settings)`. It will print True, because `'a'` is True and `'b'` is True and  `'proxy_host' in settings` is True.

Comment: `If none of the keywords are False` - What do you mean by that?

Comment: @thefourtheye:  I'm pretty sure that JesúsFlores means "If none of the _values_ associated with those keywords are False".

Comment: Yeah, my mistake I was talking about the dictionary key values...

Comment: @JesúsFlores: So you should make that more clear in your question, for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: James edited it for me. It's done. Thank you all ! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple generator expression and [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
if all(d.get(k) for k in keys):
```

**Example:**

```
keys = ['proxy_host', 'proxy_port', 'proxy_protocol']
if all(settings.get(k) for k in keys):
    print("Settings good!")
else:
    print("Missing setting!")
```

Comment: Pretty beautiful piece of code, but I'm still getting ``True`` when ie. ``proxy_port`` is an empty string (that should evaluate False)...

Comment: @JesúsFlores Ahh! See update. Basically you want to "try" to get a bunch of keys from your settings ``dict`` and default to ``None`` if they don't exist which evaluates "falsely".

Comment: You was the first answering this question. So kudos goes to you :) As suggested by @PM2Ring I've used a tuple, since they are inmutable. Thanks !!!

Comment: No worries! Thanks for using Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if ('proxy_host' in settings and isinstance(settings['proxy_host'], str)) 
   and ('proxy_port' in settings and isinstance(settings['proxy_port'], int)) 
   and ('proxy_protocol' in settings and isinstance(settings['proxy_protocol']), str)):
```

Comment: Fair call, even though the OP isn't asking about that degree of data validation. Also, it's considered more Pythonic to avoid type checking, unless it's absolutely necessary, because it interferes with [duck typing](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-duck-typing).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Edited my post. I thought is was viable, because the op has this line: `But...without bothering about what type of value has`

Comment: Haha, you're clever guys ! For real. I think your answer is technically the best of all. But I've asked for a one liner. Maybe the community should reward/thank you with upvotes, I did it ;)  Big thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that all of the keys are in the dict and map to a non-falsey value, you can check this:

```
if all(settings.get(x) for x in ['proxy_host','proxy_port', 'proxy_protocol']):
```

[`dict.get(key)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) will return `None` if the key is not in the `dict`, so you you can check "is in the dict and value is not falsey" in one go.

Comment: Nice, although I'd probably use a tuple instead of a list for the keys.

Comment: Pure awesomeness, I'm sorry james was first to answer. I've used tuple ;)